# MATLAB return current values on interrupt

Tags: matlab, return, interrupt

If I press `Ctrl + C` during the execution of a long loop, I lose all the work that has done so far. So is there a way in MATLAB that I can press `Ctrl + C`, but return the current variables?

so what I want as a pseudo-code :

```
for i=1:very_long
 do_things();
 if keypress(ctrlc_orsomeothercombo)
  disp('Im bored!');
  return;
 end
end
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn stop on errors on, then interrupting it, even with ctrl+c, brings you to the place where it was executing and you have the whole workspace available:

```
dbstop if error
```